# file download counter without database

Tags: php, download

I am a beginer in programming. i have a pdf file for download in my website. I want to know the no. of downloads. I searched in google.

and i tried something like this. http://tutorialzine.com/2010/02/php-mysql-download-counter/

But everything is with database. Since i am a beginer, i am not familiar with database.

could you please suggest me the php code for this without database

Comment: You could write some simple file handling code and store the count in a text file. PHP Manual has very good resources about it. http://www.php.net/fwrite

Comment: See also: https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2023/11/12/php-download-hit-counter/

Answer (score 1):

Well instead of a database you will have to keep a file with count

in the php file that downloads the pdf:

```
$downCount = intval( file_get_contents("/some/path/downloadCount") );
$downCount++;
file_put_contents("/some/path/downloadCount",$downCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't do it alone. It would need either a database, or an empty file to save to of some sort.

The best way is to use a database. Its probably the most easiest way as well. 
However I'd highly recommend getting in some database experience if you want to use PHP. Although database design / usage is very different to PHP, its very useful to know

Answer (score 0):

You could use the atime (access time) of the file as a counter aswell.